# Django: Unresolved reference, when trying to import an app

Tags: python, django, django-views, importerror, web-development-server

I am having issues with importing other apps and could not find a solution on the internet.
I get an *Unresolved reference 'name'*.

**Project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from users import views as user_views          #'users' and 'views' are underlined in red
from homepage import views as homepage_views   #same goes for 'homepage' and 'views'

urlpatterns = [

    path('',include("homepage.urls")),
    path('register/',user_views.register),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Project/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

**Project Structure**

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ9wU.png)

Thanks for your help and let me know if u need more information

Comment: It does not look like import error is in `urls`. Share more files that you import in. Didn't your error point to anywhere? Share the whole error message. Btw. you don't have to import `homepage_views`, because you don't use it.

Comment: I didn't import any other files.The Error occurs when I try to access URL(/register/) in my Browser, since the views function for this URL isn't imported. I added the homepage import to show that I can't import any other app in the Project.

Comment: You still didn't share the whole error message. It might point to the problem. It can be interpreter issue or python path. Is it possible to run `python manage.py runserver`?